# Google+ notification button showing count of 1 but nothing else

Tags: google-plus

What is this red notification bar in Google+?

[image: red one on top of google plus bar]

It is always at "1", and when I click it a blank popup opens.

What is it supposed to do and why is it always showing me a 1?

Answer (score 5):

That's the Google+ notifications icon. It's gray when you don't have any notifications, and red when you do.

Try clearing your cache and allowing Javascript to run on Google's domains to see if the box will fill properly.

Comment: It is a bit buggy. Sometimes reloading the page will fix it.